# Inserting (and NOT upserting) using scalikejdbc

Tags: sql, scala, scalikejdbc

I do not see a way to execute my sql insert statement without using scalikejdbc's update or execute functions, both of which turn my insert into an upsert.

```
  sql"""INSERT INTO scopes (id, name, status, level) VALUES ($id, $name, $status, $level)""".update.apply()
```

I expect the scope to be inserted only if a scope with the same ID does not exist in the DB. Otherwise I expect it to throw an error.

In reality, if the scope already exists, this code updates it.